# Android device recording wrong pageX/pageY when scrolled in Chrome browser

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, touch

While testing my app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 4.0.4, I noticed that pageY value would become incorrect after scrolling down the page.

You can test this issue using the demo provided here: 
http://api.jquery.com/event.pagey/

It appears that the pageY value being returned is actually the REAL pageY value + the document.body.scrollTop value.

This was an issue on the Galaxy tab using the default internet browser and Chrome(v38). However I also tested using Firefox and there was no issue at all.

Has anyone else had this issue? I am limited to the Android devices I am able to test with, does anybody know if this bug has been fixed in the newer versions of Android?

On the web page I am having this issue with I use the "mousemove" event to set the position of a marker on a graph. I use jquery.ui.touch.js to simulate the touch events. When "touchmove" occurs the pageY value actually is correct, the wrong value is only returned when I tap the screen on the Galaxy Tab. This makes it difficult to fix the incorrect pageY value.

Answer (score 0):

The touch events appear to have the correct pageX/pageY values for andriod, so I had to run a separate function that used these touch events if the device was android.

Here is a condensed example:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1){
   $('html').on("touchstart touchmove touchend", function(e){
       console.log(e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY);
   });
}else{
   $('html').mousemove(function(e){
       console.log(e.pageY);
   });
}
```